# Assign values from Observable to a Interface in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Im trying to assign all the values that I receive from a JSONArray into a Interface instance. The JSON data I receive are like this:

```
0:
  attack_type: "Melee"
  id: 1
  legs: 2
  localized_name: "Anti-Mage"
  name: "npc_dota_hero_antimage"
  primary_attr: "agi"
  roles: Array(3)
     0: "Carry"
     1: "Escape"
     2: "Nuker"
```

I 120 of these from a web api through a HTTP get request, and I would like each entry to be stored as a type of Interface Hero:

```
export interface Hero {
  attack_type: string;
  id: number;
  legs: number;
  localized_name: string;
  name: string;
  primary_attribute: string;
  roles: string[];
}
```

Currently Iam doing this in my component (I followed the guide in the Anuglar.io Documentation):

```
showHeroes() {
this.httpService.getHeroes()
  // clone the data object, using its known Hero properties
  .subscribe((data: Hero) => this.currentHero = {
    attack_type: (data as any).attack_type,
    id: (data as any).id,
    legs: (data as any).legs,
    localized_name: (data as any).localized_name,
    name: (data as any).name,
    primary_attribute: (data as any).primary_attribute,
    roles: (data as any).roles,
  });
```

}

But this does not seem to work, because if I console.log(currentHero.name), I get a undefined value. Does anyone know where I go wrong?

Comment: could you add `this.httpService.getHeroes()` code?

Comment: where you put console.log(currentHero.name)? Remember this is async function and if you want a log you have to put inside the subscribe function. Because you don't know when the function return the data.